# Where can I find a good guide to setup VSFTPD on Debian?

Tags: ftp, debian-lenny, vsftpd

I tried 3 different guides, and they were either outdated or they didn't work. Most of the Google results were for Ubuntu, so it didn't really apply to me because I was using Debian. I don't really know this stuff well, so when I see a guide that says to modify a directory/file that is not even in my system, I get lost. Could someone please point me to a good guide for setting up VSFTPD on Debian? I just want to setup FTP for my developer to work on my website.

Comment: 95% of the guides for Ubuntu are just as useful for Debian when you are using the official packages.  A large majority of the Ubuntu packages are directly copied from the Debian testing/unstable branch and have only minor differences.  The only major difference is that Ubuntu tends to be running a new version then the current 'stable' Debian package.

Comment: I didn't want to post this as an answer (maybe Zoredache or Zypher should, though), but here's a link to the chat transcript where this was discussed and solved:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/127/21-24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the official debian howto here: http://wiki.debian.org/Manual-Howto#FTPServer. It is pretty simple. VSFTP is very simple to configure.

A little more deeper guide is located here: http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/vsftpd.htm

If you want a GUI, try to install WebMin and the VSTPD module, like suggested in the last link.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I configure a user to the FTP for my developer?

Comment: By default VSFTPD is using system authentication for the user. Create a system user for your developer

Comment: How do I restrict the user from going into root and only go to /www/website.com?

Comment: see post below.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your comment, Doug:

You'll want to set your developer's users home directory to the /www/website.com

Then you'll lock all local users down and allow users only their home directory with:

```
chroot_local_user=yes
```

If you only want certain users to be chroot'd:

```
chroot_local_user=no
chroot_list_enable=yes
```

Then edit your /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list file to include the users you want chroot'd.

By the way, here are the **[vsftpd config docs](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html)**

Comment: Thanks Dave. I followed your instructions and I added the user to the list then `/etc/init.d/vstfpd restart`. However, I'm logging into the user that I added to chroot_list via WinSCP using SFTP and I am still able to go to the root directory. FYI, I created using `useradd`.

Comment: @Doug, SFTP has absolutely nothing to do with vsftpd.  SFTP is part of openssh-server.  If you want to chroot sftp please see [sftp ChrootDirectory](http://serverfault.com/search?q=sftp+ChrootDirectory)

Comment: vsftpd == ftp. sftp == ssh. ftps == secure ftp